# Flash seems to be caching crossdomain.xml file

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml

I have updated the crossdomain.xml security settings for my site - but it seems that the older version is being cached in both IE and Chrome.

I've checked the headers sent by the server and it's not sending any cache control headers that would be forcing the browsers to be caching crossdomain.xml.

In an attempt to get around the issue I've also linked to my crossdomain.xml file in an iframe on the site. This hasn't worked though and flash still seems to be using the old security settings.

Has anyone encountered this? How did you get around the problem?

Comment: Does it work if you clear your browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

Use following apache directives to specify caching policy for the file:

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
  <FilesMatch "crossdomain.xml">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

Flash by default ask for the XML file in the browser cache... if you want to be sure to download it put a querystring on the file name using a Date...

myfile.xml?d=01-13-2010_10:10

Comment: crossdomain.xml is typically loaded automatically, with no control over the URL, so this technique won't work.